# Apache Ignite Client restart scenario

Tags: java, ignite, gridgain

This is the scenario

1. I started the Server node.
2. I started Client Ignite node which will be done via a Java application say "X".
3. In visor I could see two nodes one is client and one is server when given command "node".
4. I killed the Java app "X" by doing "kill -9 pid".
5. Now when I go to visor terminal and enter "node" it still shows "client" and "server" nodes in the list. when asked about client node details it throws error obviously.
6. Now, when I restart the Java app "X", in that Java code again there will be an attempt to connect to Ignite server. But instead of connecting it is printing these logs so many times

`"org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger" "info" "INFO" "" "284" "Accepted incoming communication connection [locAddr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:47101, rmtAddr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:62856]" "" "" "" "" "" "" "1587013526124" "" "" "" "" "" "" "ROOT" "{""service"":"""",""logger_name"":""org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi""}"`

7. It's not connecting and continuing to execute the code in Java. So the application is not resuming. And I found this is Ignite server log

[10:37:57] Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: Checkpoint read lock acquisition has been timed out.]]
[10:37:57,739][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#46][GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager] Checkpoint read lock acquisition has been timed out.
class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager$CheckpointReadLockTimeoutException: Checkpoint read lock acquisition has been timed out.
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.failCheckpointReadLock(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1708)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.checkpointReadLock(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1640)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.initTopologies(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1078)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:944)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3258)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3104)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[10:39:21,547][SEVERE][tcp-disco-msg-worker-[693d29cd 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo0:47501 crd]-#2][G] Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [workerName=db-checkpoint-thread, threadName=db-checkpoint-thread-#59, blockedFor=209s]

I am assuming here that since I am force shutting down the Java application which starts Ignite Client node, it's possible that there would be some topology imbalance that might happen.

Can someone please suggest, if at all I force kill the Client application, is there a correct way to restart the Client application such that it'll continue re-establishing the connection with Ignite server and continue working?

Comment: Do you have any custom timeouts specified in your configurations? This scenario is possible when you have very long timeouts.

Comment: Hi Alamar. In both the Server and Client Ignite configs, we have set two timeouts... one is ClientFailureDetectionTimeout and the other is FailureDetectionTimeout. Both are set 1 minute. Our application is in the development phase. When developing we are putting breakpoints and checking by executing each line. While doing so, caches are being closed causing us to not debug. So we set it high like 1 min.. But while moving it to production thinking it make it less like 30 seconds.. Can you please tell me what is the issue here?

Comment: I understood Alamar. It's because the killed node not being updated in topology. When we removed that timeouts, it's working fine. Thank you. Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, you should not expect node to be dropped, and a new one to join, before the timeout runs off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is possible when you have very long timeouts.

You should not expect node to be dropped, and a new one to join, before all timeout runs off, such as, network timeout, socket write timeout, failure detection timeout. That, unless you do graceful shutdown.